# How many tags are needed in this question?

Tags: discussion

My question is brought on by recent tag cleanup activities on SciFi.SE.

This question is the one I'm specifically wondering about, but I'm wondering in general also:

[Why would you lie to your children about Santa?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/19788/why-would-you-lie-to-your-children-about-santa)

On SciFi (and probably other stacks, but I don't follow meta on any others), it's been decided that certain tags should only be used if it could attract "experts" of that tag.

To me, I see that question as pertaining to something like [traditions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traditions), and probably [santa](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/santa), but the rest of the tags only seem tangentially related. Using both [christmas](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christmas) and [holidays](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holidays) seems redundant (but would be less so if the question were about holiday mascots in general, like the Easter bunny included).

So, what's our stance? Are we tagging for breadth, or depth?

Comment: I tend to tag as much as possible, but that is more of a personal habit (e.g. I like to make categories and groups of things) than a site policy. I can readily admit I may have been overzealous in this case :)

Comment: I see two meta.stackexchange questions that would be relevant: [How do I correctly tag my questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions) and [Why do we tag questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions) -- I look forward to discussion.

Comment: I want to note, that this wasn't supposed to specifically call out @Erica. I saw all the tags and thought they were a bit much, and when I went to edit them out I saw that they'd be edited *in*. It made me chuckle.

Comment: No worries. I hadn't given much thought to tags, but this is helping me realize they could use some attention generally. And I got to read some new general meta posts :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm honestly not sure what best practice would be here. On some of the sites I moderate the habit seems to be as few tags as possible, whereas here we use more.

On Security.SE, for example, there are some individuals who specialise in one particular area, so they follow one tag. If a question uses that tag they will see it quickly and be able to answer it. Parenting.SE feels a lot less specialised - raising children requires abilities across a wide range of disciplines, so pinning it down to a small subset of specific tags isn't easy.

The overarching requirement is to use tags where it will helps people find the question. If a specific question requires one then that's fine, but if you think more will help then that's also fine.

So my thinking is that using fewer, slightly more generic tags is more helpful here, rather than specifying to the n'th degree.

The example above is possibly a little duplication, but I don't think it harms the question at all.

Comment: Reading the meta Erica commented on the OP, "Why do we tag", the #1 reason is to connect experts to questions. It doesn't seem to be about visitors (usually people with *questions*) finding questions, but helping the people with *answers* find the questions. It also mentions that the title and question get indexed by search engines very well, and quickly, so the tags aren't for off-site traffic. With that in mind, do you think we should lean towards fewer, more directly relevant tags?

Comment: yes - 'connecting experts to questions' is the specific part that is important. As you see, my opinion is that fewer is better, but I can't find anything SE-wide that explicitly states one way or the other. I'll clarify with a wee edit.

Answer (score 1):

My feeling tends towards having tags that are relevant to the question itself (not just a word contained in the question).  For this question I think the question is asking about [santa](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/santa), specifically, and something that I can't really coherently describe about giving children age-appropriate information versus lying (so, stork-brings-babies types of things). Maybe [difficult-conversations](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difficult-conversations) or something like that.

I don't like [lying](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lying) as that seems more likely to be children lying.  I don't think it needs the other holiday tags - other than santa, it's not really a question about the holidays, and I don't see how [presents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presents) is related.  Yes, kids get presents, but that is unrelated to Santa in most cases.

Comment: I'm struggling to remember why I added [tag:presents] -- probably because of the strong association between Santa and gift-giving.

Comment: I think difficult-conversations is probably an appropriate tag that we could find other questions that could benefit from it's use.